# HTML Div is clipping Image as Browser Window gets resized

Tags: html, css, web

I have an HTML Table, where a Cell contains multiple sequential HTML Divs.  In one of the Divs is an Image that floats to the right.

**The Problem:** As the browser window is resized and the Div surrounding the image expands or contracts, the Image can get vertically clipped at the bottom when the Div height dynamically changes to be less than the Image height.

The [Example Page](http://nounz.if4it.com) where you can see the problem occur is at: http://nounz.if4it.com, where the globe, in the body and on the right, is the image I'm talking about.

The code looks something like...

```
<td class="td_BodyRight">
  <div class="div_RootBody">
    <h1 style="text-align:center; font: bold 1.5em Arial;">Welcome to the Home Page for this Example Web Site</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="div_RootBody">
     <img style="float:right; padding:3px; width:150px; height:150px" src="./IMAGES/MAIN/globe1.png" alt="Global NOUNZ"/
     <p><b>Note:</b> NOUNZ is a registered trademark of the International Foundation for Information Technology (IF4IT).</p>
     <p>This entire Web Site was generated, in minutes, by the IF4IT NOUNZ platform and is in place as a live demonstration so that people can see and understand, for themselves, what the output of a NOUNZ compiled data set looks and feels like.</p>
     <p>It should also be noted that the data contained and represented within this Web Site is strictly fabricated and for demonstration purposes.  Such data is not intended nor should it be interpreted to represent anyone or anything outside this demonstration.</p>
  </div>
    .
    .
    .
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to ensure that the image doesn't get clipped?

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tested it and it looks like "overflow:visible" is what works best.

Comment: Friend, if that's the solution then you should upvote me not downvote me

Answer (score 0):

so based on you comment what you need it this:

```
<div class="div_RootBody">
     <img style="float:right; padding:3px; width:150px; height:150px" src="./IMAGES/MAIN/globe1.png" alt="Global NOUNZ"/
     <p><b>Note:</b> NOUNZ is a registered trademark of the International Foundation for Information Technology (IF4IT).</p>
     <p>This entire Web Site was generated, in minutes, by the IF4IT NOUNZ platform and is in place as a live demonstration so that people can see and understand, for themselves, what the output of a NOUNZ compiled data set looks and feels like.</p>
     <p>It should also be noted that the data contained and represented within this Web Site is strictly fabricated and for demonstration purposes.  Such data is not intended nor should it be interpreted to represent anyone or anything outside this demonstration.</p>
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
```

So the important thing is the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the bottom. This will *anchor* the bottom of your div so it will expand correctly with the image changing sizes.

Comment: Hi Liam,  The problem is that the user can add their own images, which could (and will) easily vary in size.  Using a fixed "min-height" value doesn't solve the problem.  I need something that can handle any sized image.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: @InformationTechnology, changed my answer based on what you said. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

In your div class, add:
overflow:visible

Comment: I tried it and I found that using "overflow:visible" doesn't work for images.  It only works for text.  I need a solution that addresses images.  Thanks.

Comment: After all this is the solution that worked so you should've marked it right and upvote it, not downvote it and post the same thing as your answer.